# Splitting comma separated values to multiple columns

Tags: sql, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to split a comma separated column to multiple columns using SQL such that each separated value is under its own column on Snowflake

This is a sample of my table

```
"2015-01-01","00:52:44",161144,"3.1.0","x86_64","mingw32","Formula","1.1-2","US",1
```

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM "TUTORIAL"."PUBLIC"."CRAN_LOGS" STRING_SPLIT('date','time','size','r_version','r_arch','r_os','package','version','country','ip_id',';')
```

This is giving me the error message:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 59 unexpected
> ''date''. syntax error line 1 at position 149 unexpected ')'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [**split_part**](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html)

```
SPLIT_PART(<string>, <delimiter>, <partNumber>)
```

---

Just be careful with column names though. Some of them could be reserved keywords in SQL and might throw an error

```
with your_table as 
(select 'date,time,size,r_version,r_arch,r_os,package,version,country,ip_id' as col)

select split_part(col,',',1) as date,
       split_part(col,',',2) as time,
       split_part(col,',',3) as size,
       split_part(col,',',4) as r_version,
       split_part(col,',',5) as r_arch,
       split_part(col,',',6) as r_os,
       split_part(col,',',7) as package,
       split_part(col,',',8) as version,
       split_part(col,',',9) as country,
       split_part(col,',',10) as ip_id
from your_table;
```